# Spark Installation Memory issues

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

This question has been asked but I am still facing issues.

```
hduser@sanjeebpanda-VirtualBox:/usr/local/spark$ sbt/sbt assembly
```

Using `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386` as default JAVA_HOME.

Note, this will be overridden by -java-home if it is set.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Regards
Sanjeeb

Answer (score 0):

What the error message appears to be saying is there is not enough memory on the machine to allocate the necessary java heap space.

I would check ~/.sbtconfig to see what the Xmx and Xms values are set to, and try to lower these. Though since these are the defaults it may cause you other issues.

Best solution would be to use another machine with larger memory available.

Cheers

Comment: I have the same issue when installing spark on my VM.I did a sudo find / -name .sbtconfig, but find nothing. Where should I get that file?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the same issue when installing Spark. And after setting the _JAVA_OPTIONS, it works.

Following is what I have used. Change the memory size according to your machine:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xmx128M -Xmx256M'
```